# c# passing values through constructor but are not displayed in a textbox

Tags: c#

i have passes some values though a constructor from one from to another. the values are successfully transferred in another form through constructor but when i display them in a textbox the values become null and the textbox remains empty. i am showing the code of the constructor for both forms.

starting form which opens another form

```
 private void lbl_imgpass_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        string img = img_name.Text;
        Setimgpass st = new Setimgpass(img);
        st.Show();
    }
```

form1(from where the values are transferred to another form)

```
  else
        {
             first = textBox2.Text;
             second = textBox3.Text;
             third = textBox4.Text;
             Adduser add = new Adduser(x1low, x1up, x2low, x2up, x3low, x3up, y1low, y1up, y2low, y2up, y3low, y3up, first, second, third);
          this.Hide();

        }
```

second form(where the values are received)

```
     public Adduser(string x1low, string x1up, string x2low, string x2up, string x3low, string x3up, string y1low, string y1up, string y2low, string y2up, string y3low, string y3up,string first, string second, string third)

        {
          InitializeComponent();
          frst = first;
          secnd = second;
          thrd = third;
          lowx1 = x1low;
          upx1 = x1up;
          lowx2 = x2low;
          upx2 = x2up;
          lowx3 = x3low;
          upx3 = x3up;
          lowy1 = y1low;
          upy1 = y1up;
          lowy2 = y2low;
          upy2 = y2up;
          lowy3 = y3low;
          upy3 = y3up;
          txt_imgpass.Text = frst + " " + secnd + " " + thrd;

      }
```

txt_imgpass is the textbox in which i want values.

Comment: Where is the call to Show the form instance (add) created in your code above?

Comment: you mean to say add.show() line?

Comment: Yes, you have created that instance with new then it seems that you don't show it.

Comment: let me try this and i'll tell what happened.

Comment: yeah this worked but sadly the values which were already present in the second form vanished when add.show() was executed

Comment: i have edited my code now have a look at it

Comment: let me show you the control flow its user register -> form2 -> user register so according to you when i use add.show() the values which were already present on user register previously are gone and only the current value in the textbox remains i hope now you have understood what i wanted to say?

Answer (score 0):

In the first form the values are passed to the object "add" that you created .

You can simply use static variables to pass data from one form to another .

**EDIT**

You might as well want to try something like this instead of static variables

Form 1 :
assuming this is the button you click on to show the second form

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form = new Form2(textBox1.Text);
        form.Show();
    }
```

in Form 2 you can do something like this

```
public Form2(string text)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        label1.Text = text;
    }
```

Comment: thanks but i am bit confused about these static variables so please can you help in declaring them how can i make them static variables and access them in another form.

Comment: can you please explain further more how your first form look like and the second form two

Comment: i have edited my code now have a look at it actually one form is opening on the click of a label without hiding the previous form then in that values are entered and when clicking on save button the values are passed through a constructor and second form is hidden and the previous form is seen which was not hidden

Comment: everything looks fine to me , just as Steve said all you need is to show the form , add.Show();

Comment: let me show you the control flow its user register -> form2 -> user register so according to you when i use add.show() the values which were already present on user register previously are gone and only the current value in the textbox remains i hope now you have understood what i wanted to say?

Comment: by static variable: In Form1: 'static string str;' and initialize 'str'. In Form2: 'new Form1 f1 = New Form1();' and 'label1.Text = f1.str'